# P5.js curveVertex function is closing at a point

Tags: javascript, geometry, p5.js, perlin-noise

I've created a noise function that pairs with a circle function to create a random noise circle thing that looks pretty cool. My problem is the `curveVertex` function in P5.js works correctly except for the connection of the first and last vertex. My code is:

```js
let start = Array(50).fill(0); // dont change
let amount = 1; // amount of shapes
let gap = 30; // between shapes
let amplify = 50; // 0 -->
let colorSpeed = 1; // 1 - 9
let colorSeparation = 3; // 0 - 80 recomended 0 - 10

function setup() {

  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  
  for(let  i = 0 ; i < start.length; i++){
    start[i] = random(i);
  }
  
}

function draw() {
  
  background(0);
  
  for(let dnc = (amount + 1) * gap; dnc > gap; dnc -= gap){
    drawNoiseCircle(dnc, getNoise(start.length));
  }
    
  start = start.map( c => c + 0.01 );
  
}

function getNoise(amount){
  
  let lengths = [];
  
  for(let i = 1; i < amount + 1; i++){
    
    let n1 = noise(start[i - 1]);
    let noise1 = map(n1, 0, 1, -amplify, amplify);

    lengths.push(abs(-noise1));
    
  }
  
  return lengths;
  
}

function drawNoiseCircle(radius, lengths){
  
  colorMode(HSB);
  fill(((frameCount + radius) * colorSeparation)/-map(colorSpeed, 1, 10, -10, -1) % 360, 100, 50);
  noStroke()

  let x;
  let y;
  
  beginShape();
  
  for(let l = 0; l < lengths.length; l++){
    
    x = Math.cos(radians(l * 360 / lengths.length)) * (radius + lengths[l]) + width/2;
    y = Math.sin(radians(l * 360 / lengths.length)) * (radius + lengths[l]) + height/2;
    
    curveVertex(x, y);
    
  }
  
  endShape(CLOSE);
  
  stroke("black");
  line(width/2, height/2, width, height/2);
  
  line(width/2, height/2 + 9, width, height/2 + 9);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

I understand the `endShape(CLOSED)` closes the shape with a straight line, but I'm not sure any other way to close the shape.

You can see the pointed edge on the right side, directly in the middle of the shape.

**!EDIT!**

I've added lines to the shape to show the line segment that isn't affected by the curve vertex. Also, I understand it may not be a very significant problem, but if the amount of vertexes shrink, it becomes a much bigger problem (eg. a square or a triangle).

Comment: Awesome animation! For me, it's extremely difficult to spot the issue.

Comment: If your first point and last point coincide then `endShape()` can do its thing without a straight line (or, more accurately, a zero-length line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I won't have time to dive deep and debug the actual issue with curveVertex (or it's math) at the time, but it seems there's something interesting with `curveVertex()` in particular.

@Ouoborus point makes sense and the function "should" behave that way (and it was with `vertex()`, but not `curveVertex()`). For some reason `curveVertex()` requires looping over the not just the first point again, but the second and third.

Here's basic example:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 300);
  
  background(220);
  
  let numPoints = 6;
  let angleIncrement = TWO_PI / numPoints;
  let radius = 120;
  
  beginShape();
  for(let i = 0 ; i < numPoints + 3; i++){
    let angle = angleIncrement * i;
    let x = 150 + cos(angle) * radius;
    let y = 150 + sin(angle) * radius;
    curveVertex(x, y);
  }
  endShape();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Try decreasing `numPoints + 3` to `numPoints + 2` or notice the behaviour you're describing.
(I could speculate it might have something to do with how `curveVertex()` (Catmull-Rom splines) are implemented in p5 and how many coordinates/points it requires, but this isn't accurate without reading the source code and debugging a bit)

Here's a version of your code using the above notes:

```js
let start = Array(30).fill(0);

let colorSpeed = 1; // 1 - 9
let colorSeparation = 3; // 0 - 80 recomended 0 - 10

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  colorMode(HSB);
  noStroke();
  // init noise seeds
  for(let  i = 0 ; i < start.length; i++){
    start[i] = random(i);
  }
}

function getNoise(seeds, amplify = 50){
  let amount = seeds.length;
  let lengths = [];
  
  for(let i = 1; i < amount + 1; i++){
    
    let n1 = noise(seeds[i - 1]);
    let noise1 = map(n1, 0, 1, -amplify, amplify);

    lengths.push(abs(-noise1));
    
  }
  
  return lengths;
  
}

function drawNoiseCircle(radius, lengths){
  let sides = lengths.length;
  let ai = TWO_PI / sides;
  let cx = width * 0.5;
  let cy = height * 0.5;
  
  fill(((frameCount + radius) * colorSeparation)/-map(colorSpeed, 1, 10, -10, -1) % 360, 100, 50);
  
  beginShape();
  for(let i = 0 ; i < sides + 3; i++){
    let noiseRadius = radius + lengths[i % sides];
    let a = ai * i;
    let x = cx + cos(a) * noiseRadius;
    let y = cy + sin(a) * noiseRadius;
    curveVertex(x, y);
  }
  endShape();
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  // draw with updated perlin noise values
  drawNoiseCircle(120, getNoise(start));
  // increment noise seed
  start = start.map( c => c + 0.01 );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```